# Transparent ListView over VideoView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-videoview

I'm trying to create a ListView over a full screen video window. I've checked the several posts here, but still unable to get a working solution. What I have right now is, the list is sort of translucent when the selection is highlighted. As & when I move the selection, the video becomes translucent only in that area. Essentially, video can be partially seen behind the blue bar. The rest is hidden. Ideally, I'd like to achieve this:

1. The listview should show up only in the left corner
2. Video playing behind should be transparent

Here is what I have now:

```
public void ShowList(String[] my_list)
{
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main, android.R.id.list, my_list));

    // Get an object for the list
    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    //listView.setCacheColorHint(0);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
        {
            InitiatePlayback(position);
        }
    });
}
```

Layout is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/RelativeScreen"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
  <VideoView
   android:id="@+id/VideoWindow"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" >
  </VideoView>
  <TextView
      android:id="@android:id/list"
      android:layout_width="300sp"
      android:layout_height="40sp">
  </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Would truly appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging around, found from another post that I needed this setting in the manifest for the activity:

android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"

It works very well now